# Phone frozen for a short time after unplugging from charger

Tags: nexus-4

When my screen is off and I unplug my Nexus 4 from the charger, the phone is frozen with the screen off for about 10 seconds. Power/volume buttons have no effect and the phone will not wake.

If the screen is on when I unplug, there is no problem and the phone is responsive.  This isn't really a big issue, but I'm just curious as to why it happens and what's going on with my phone during that time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a nexus 4? This should not be happening with your phone as nexus 4 is quite a fast one. It happens with slow phones especially when you have battery saving apps installed. Try formatting your phone and deleting apps you don't need.

Comment: Yes it is a Nexus 4.  I don't have any battery-saving apps installed, and not even very many apps.  I can't afford to do a wipe at the moment, but I'll give that a shot sometime and report back.

Comment: Do you have other apps that work or respond to your phone being connected to power supply ? Uninstall those. Also check the apps you installed just before this problem took place.

Comment: You can also backup before formatting. Android makes backing up quite easy.

Comment: I don't have any apps set up to do anything when the charger is plugged in.  The phone responds by turning the screen on, but that's it.  When I plug in the charger or remove the charger while the screen is on, everything is fine.

Comment: Then I am unsure of the problem. Sorry.